# How to get all process in task manager with Microsoft API using C++ in win 64bit

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a block code below.

I want to get all processes in tasks manager with C++ but it not work.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>

void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                   PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                   FALSE, processID );
    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModulesEx( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
             &cbNeeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                               sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }
    _tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( void )
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
        {
            PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get all processes in task manager but it return error like this images.
[image]

How to solve it, thanks for any answer.

I try to get all processes in task manager.

Comment: Do step by step using the debugger and check what the functions return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to link with Psapi.lib.

Your errors are linker errors. The linker is creating the final exe, after the compiler compiled the source files to object files.
When you use functions like `EnumProcessModulesEx` from from `<psapi.h>`, you need to link with their implementation.

It is recommended to read the documentation for API you are using.
For example: [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodulesex).

Comment: How to be able to linker as you say. I tried but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Which IDE are you using ? Which compiler ? In MSVC you go to project settings -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, and add  Psapi.lib there.

Comment: I use Dev C++ which is good for a beginner like me. I'm quite confused about the linker

Comment: I suggest you search for some basic tutorial about compilation and linkage, and specifically with Dev C++ (I am not familiar with it).

Comment: @blackTurle: I suggest to you that "making simple things hard (like adding a library to your linker command line)" is the opposite of "good for a beginner"